# Search bar doesn't display table after one search

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out why after I search for something and then delete that search query to search something else the table doesn't display anything but is still searching for the right answer.

So in the jsfiddle if you type 001 then delete that to try to look for 002 the table that was displayed doesn't show up anymore. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    let rows = document.querySelector("#Test").rows;// or much precise query if needed

function check(event) {
  let caps = event.target.value.toUpperCase();
  let hyphen = caps.replace(/[-]/g, ""); // Edit : caps + hyphen will work

  // Browse all rows to check if input matching and hide/show
  // Fortunately row.textContent yields all texts values :)
  for(let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {  
    let row = rows[i];

    // test caps length to allow revert to all hidden when no text to match
    if(caps.length && (row.textContent.indexOf(caps) >= 0 || row.textContent.indexOf(hyphen) >= 0)) { row.style.display = "";} // process next row
  else{  
    row.style.display = 'none'; // Hide row (avoid an else)  
  }


    }}
document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('keyup', check, true);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jx8vw64L/9/

Comment: You never restore the style.display=none. It will not miraculously change back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the

```
caps.length &&
```

in your if

```
 if((row.textContent.indexOf(caps) >= 0 || row.textContent.indexOf(hyphen) >= 0)) 
 { 
     row.style.display = "";
 } // process next row
 else
 { 
      row.style.display = 'none'; // Hide row (avoid an else)  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you html markup like this

```
 function textChange() {
   //DO SOME CODE
 }
<input type="text" name="foo" onKeyUp="return textChange()" />
```

OR WITH JQUERY

```
$('.target').change(function() {
   //DO SOME CODE
});
```